# A question about the Buchsbaum-Eisenbud-Horrocks Conjecture

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra

It's known that Mark E. Walker [proved the "weaker" version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02560.pdf) of Buchsbaum-Eisenbud-Horrocks' Conjecture (BEH). Although the claim was stated to hold in arbitrary field $k$, Walker's proof does not seem to include the case when $k$ is of characteristic $2$.

> **QUESTIONS.** Has weak BEH been proved or disproved when $k$ is of $char=2$? Why does this special characteristic resist, philosophically or technically?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the cyclic Adams operation $\psi^2_{cy}$ is not defined when the characteristic of the base field is 2. There are some notes [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/ca/Walker.pdf) by Mark Walker himself that do a good job of explaining Adams operations for commutative algebraists.